# How to tell the line number when `die`?

Tags: perl, line-numbers, die

I'd like to write sth like:

```
die "Error in file $0 line number $line_number_of_this_cmd_in_file \n";
```

In my perl script file.

Any help?
Thx a lot!

(perl 5)

Comment: Check out [Carp](http://search.cpan.org/~zefram/Carp-1.3301/lib/Carp.pm)'s `croak`.  If you use `croak` instead of `die` you can get a full stack trace when running with `perl -MCarp=verbose script.pl`.

Comment: `die` already reports the line number, do you want to change the number?

Answer (score 10):

If you do not put \n at the end of the string you pass to die, then perl will automatically add the line number.

Otherwise, the token `__LINE__` will give you the current line number in your script (and `__FILE__` gives the current file name).

Unless you meant the current line number of the file you just read from - that is available in $.

Answer (score 8):

That is quite easy: Drop the `\n` at the end of the line and `die` will append whatever message you wrote with the name of the script and the line number.
For example:

```
die "Encountered error 15 ";
```

will result in it printing:

```
"Encountered error 15 at script.pl line 42\n"
```

or whatever is applicable.